# Facebook::Messenger::Subscriptions::Error (An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, webhooks, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm creating a facebook chatbot with Rails using a gem called `facebook-messenger` [ https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger ] and the `figaro` gem to store my api keys and tokens.

However, I'm not being able to connect the webhook because every time it makes a call to the `callback_url` to check for the `verify_token`, it gives me the following error on terminal: `Facebook::Messenger::Subscriptions::Error (An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.)` and this one on facebook: `The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="992096906", received="Error; wrong verif..."`

I have checked and my `access_token` is right for the fb page I'm trying to connect to and the ngrok tunnel server I'm using for the `callback_url` works on the browser (meaning it takes me to the blank page since there is no view for that page and I can access every other page of the app through the ngrok). The `verify_token` is also exactly the same in the app (in my `application.yml` file)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rGV9.png) and in facebook itself.

I have also added the submissions for `pages_messaging`. I'm wondering whether I should have some code in the `bot.rb` file which is the end point of my `callback_url`? If so, what should it look like? [I've seen some online but they're for PHP or JS and I'm already using the `mount Facebook::Messenger::Server, at: 'bot'` on my `routes.rb` file]

SOS

[Screenshot of error in facebook trying to connect the webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRz55.png)

[Screenshot of error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRz55.png)